# Subdivide elements of a list into separate columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to subdivide elements of a list into separate columns.

Sample data:

```
d <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

This is a solution for 1 elements of a list:

```
numrows <- (row(as.matrix(d[[1]])) %% 2)
TabNum <- sapply(1:2, function(x) as.matrix(d[[1]])[numrows==numrows[x,], ,drop=FALSE])
```

How do I do this efficiently for a whole list?

Here is start, but later I found it troublesome to compbine with `sapply`, anyway this is real hack, there must be neater solution.

```
numrows.list <- lapply(1:length(d), function(i) (row(as.matrix(d[[i]])) %% 2))
```

So for the `d` list there would be 4 columns. So the desired output is:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]    1    2   1    2
[2,]    3    4   3    4
[3,]    5    6   5    6
[4,]    7    8   7    8
```

Comment: @akrun: I have to really define first what I actually need! :)

Comment: @Maximillian It is my first, didn't see the `row` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to work here

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(d, function(x) matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    1    2
# [2,]    3    4    3    4
# [3,]    5    6    5    6
# [4,]    7    8    7    8
```

Comment: Why I could not figure this out myself?! Thank you!